# Isolate pixels from trend raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, overlay

I'm using the generate trend raster tool (Mann-Kendall) and would like to isolate the resultant pixels from the sen's slope band that also show "significance" from the p-value band at the same pixel. So the result would show only the slope pixels (with their original values) that are actually significant. How should I do this?

Comment: What software or programming language are you using? You should add a tag for that.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks. tag added for arcgis-pro

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of [Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm) and [Extract by Mask](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm). First reclassify your p-value band into a binary classification of "significant" vs "not significant". Then use the binary mask you just made in Extract by Mask to only extract the significant pixels from the trend band.